# Combinations with committee members

Tags: combinations, permutation

Question, with 30 members in a club: 18 are men & 12 are women.
A committee is formed with 6 members, but a requirement that there be at least as many as women as men.  How many different committees can be formed?

Kind of confused with the word of the questioning, but I have attempted that I believe they are asking 12 women at least.  So - 12C6 = 2310 committees can be formed? Not sure if its correct.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a mathematical puzzle.

Comment: The chapter is called "Permutations and Combinations", so I'm not sure how i'm off topic with this question.  It deals with Combination.  Not sure how else i'll rephrase the question, when its all about combinations.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Alright.  Well the other user helped , could have not brought that vote down, but whatever.  Thanks for the reply regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, this is not a programming question but a mathematical problem.

Second, I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly but here's my interpretation: Because you are required to have *at least as many* women as men on a committee and since there are 6 members in each committee it follows that the *minimum* number of women in a committee would have to be 3. So there are only 4 possible types of committees:

- 3 male : 3 female
- 2 male : 4 female
- 1 male : 5 female
- 0 male : 6 female (as pointed out by Philip Sheard)

Then, you could use the following logic:

For committees formed of 3 male and 3 female, the number of possible committees would be the number of possible combinations of elements from the two sets:

- The set of all possible combinations of 3 males from the total 18 `=C(18,3)`
- The set of all possible combinations of 3 females from the total 12 `=C(12,3)`

Let's call `CM = C(18,3)` the number of different combinations of 3 men can be formed from the 18 male members; And let's call `CF = C(12,3)` the number of different combinations of 3 women can be formed from the 12 female members.

The result for a 3:3 type committee would be `CF x CM`

```
CF x CM = C(18,3) * C(12,3)
CF x CM = (18! * 12!) / (3! * 15! * 3! * 9!)
```

Then, you could use the same logic to compute the number of committees for 2:4 and then for 1:5, and finally for 0:6.

Summing them all should give you the final result.

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply.  Reading it help me understand it.  I will give this a checkmark for being solved.

Comment: “First off, this is not a programming question but a mathematical problem.” So you answer it to send the message that the OP should ask his third math homework question here?

Comment: @PascalCuoq - you're right.. I suppose I could have ignored it but I figured I could help so I did it anyway

Comment: At least he gave the wrong answer.

Comment: @PhilipSheard - what do you mean?

Comment: Your answer fails to include the case where all 6 members are female.

Comment: @PhilipSheard - Yep, you're right! I've updated the answer. By the way, I believe your answer also includes some invalid combinations.

Comment: You are right. That will show him.

Answer (score 0):

In your notation, the answer is 12C3 * 27C3. Choose 3 women at random, then choose any 3 other people.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But since this is a "Math" problem, i'm going to stop posting before I get any more downvotes for being off topic